# struct node* next understanding

Tags: pointers, linked-list, cs50

In pset 5s walkthrough, the node struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct node 
{   
   int value;
   struct node* next 
} node;
node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
cursor = head;
 //update the cursor
cursor->next
```

And when we then use the cursor -> next statement, to jump to the next node. How does the struct exactly know to jump to the next, what connects them?

I understand that the cursor points to the "current node" and then -> next will go to the next node in the linked list.

When defining the node struct, is next a predefined keyword?

As far as my understanding of pointers, we are creating a pointer to the struct node and calling it "next", but I don't see how the nodes are connected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as head is pointing to the current node, `next` within the current node points to some other node. But to move to the `next` node, you have to write `cursor = head - > next` or `cursor = cursor - > next` and not just `cursor - > next`. That is, you have to move the cursor to the next node to access it's data. Note that you have to allocate a node to the next using maybe `cursor - > next = malloc(sizeof(node)) ;`. Otherwise you'll get a segmentation fault if you try to access the data of the next node. Maybe you should go through the pointers and structures part once more to understand it clearly. Make sure you see the shorts as well.